# concatenating numpy row elements

Tags: python-3.x

If I have three numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4],[5,6]])
b = np.array([[7, 8], [9,10],[11,12]])
c = np.array([[13, 14], [15,16], [17,18]])
dstacker = np.dstack((a,b,c))
```

I want to save this to a file in the following format:

```
1713, 2814, 3915, 41016, 51117, 61218
```

Having tried many methods and having searched stack exchange exhaustively, Im currently stumped. What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this isn't the most elegant solution, but I figured out my formatting problem by doing the following with help from a generous member here -- Donkey Kong:

```
new_dstack_list =[''.join([hex(ele) for ele in row]) for dim in dstacker for row in dim]  #supplied by Donkey Kong

number_of_elements = len(new_dstack_list)

for i in range(0,number_of_elements):
    new_dstack_list[i] = new_dstack_list[i].replace(' ', '').replace('0x', '')
```

saving the file:

```
with open(save_file_path,'w') as f:
    f.write(",".join(list))
    f.close()
```

and now the output is:

```
17d,28e,39f,4a10,5b11,6c12
```

Thanks again for the help, it gave me  a push in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized approach after scaling each element with appropriate `10-powered` scaling and summing to simulate the concatenating effect -

```
# Calculate each elements number of digits
pows = np.floor(np.log10(dstacker)).astype(int)+1

# 10 powered scalings needed for each elements except the last column
scale = (10**pows[:,:,1:])[:,:,::-1].cumprod(axis=-1)[:,:,::-1]

# Finally get the concatenated number using the scalings and adding last col
num = ((dstacker[:,:,:-1]*scale).sum(-1) + dstacker[:,:,-1]).ravel()
```

Leftover work is writing the `1D` output array `num` to a file.

Sample run -

```
In [7]: dstacker
Out[7]: 
array([[[    1,    27,    13],
        [27800,     8,    14]],

       [[54543,   559,     5],
        [    4,    10, 17776]],

       [[    5,    11,    17],
        [    6,     2,    18]]])

In [8]: pows = np.floor(np.log10(dstacker)).astype(int)+1
   ...: scale = (10**pows[:,:,1:])[:,:,::-1].cumprod(axis=-1)[:,:,::-1]
   ...: num = ((dstacker[:,:,:-1]*scale).sum(-1) + dstacker[:,:,-1]).ravel()
   ...: 

In [9]: num
Out[9]: array([    12713,  27800814, 545435595,  41017776,     51117,      6218])
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. Any idea for a workaround when one of the elements are zero? (The cumulative sum would give incorrect values then)